# Эмулировать ajax запрос при помощи curl запроса

Tags: php, ajax, curl, xhr

У меня есть серверное апи, в котором используются сессии, ориентировочно он выглядит так:

```
if(!session_id()) @session_start();
$_SESSION['test']=$_POST['value'];
```

Если обращаться к нему с клиента XHR запросом, jquery ajax'ом в частности, то всё впорядке, данные сохраняются в суперглобальном массиве `$_SESSION` и я могу их использовать при последующих ajax запросах от того же пользователя:

```
$.post('api.php',{value:123})
```

Однако если я вызываю апи из другого php скрипта curl запросом, то сессия не закрепляется за пользователем, а живёт своей отдельной жизнью:

```
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'localhost/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"value=123");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1);
    $res=curl_exec($ch);
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать curl запрос максимально похожем на ajax запрос, чтобы, по крайней мере, php сессия закреплялась за пользователем, который этот curl активировал? Если я правильно понимаю, то нехватает каких-то заголовков, но я плохо разбираюсь в устройстве обоих технологий, потому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам нужно передавать "куку" с идентификатором сессии при запросе через curl...

```
$coockie = "Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id();
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",$coockie);
.....
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Это минимум который нужно передавать, если у вас используются не только сессии - нужно передавать и все прочие куки =)

Comment: Да, установка заголовков было тем, чего мне не хватало. Однако `Content-Type` заголовок я поменял на `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, иначе не работало. Спасибо.

Comment: application/json - просто то что используется у меня(откуда и выдрал строки), а так да, вам нужно выбрать ваш тип запроса =)